# Why does PHP not support multithreading?

Tags: php, multithreading, language-design

I've read everywhere that PHP does not support multithreading but there are workarounds. But *why* does PHP not support multithreading? For a server-side scripting language, that seems like a glaring omission.

Comment: I think you hit it when you said scripting language.  It's not really meant so much as a full blown solution to problems, it's more of a glue.  If you're doing something that requires threading, you might be better off using something that's more performance oriented than PHP. PHP is ... uh ... quirky, for lack of a less offensive term.

Comment: Well...Python is often considered "scripting" (though it blurs the line with full-blown PLs). And AFAIK, you can use threads in Python, even in web-dev right? http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Comment: You sort of can.  Threading in python is somewhat crippled.  The same rule applies though, if you're doing something that's seriously efficiency driven, python isn't a good choice.  Python is, at least, generally considered to be designed better than PHP.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Edit several years later:  you can use `pthreads` for PHP multithreading, but do you really want to?

I'm not sure if `pthreads` is available on many hosting environments.  And frankly I am not in a rush to find out.

One of PHP's biggest strengths for many applications is its isolation: one process, one request.  Multi-processing is usually done by queuing a job during a request and executing it somewhere else.  For example, Laravel has "queues":  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

---

Because PHP was not written with multithreading in mind and it would be a huge effort (basically a 100% rewrite) to add it in.

Some would say that PHP is pretty much a gigantic pile:  http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/.  From that perspective it is not surprising that threading is not included.

Comment: So...it's just late to the (multithreading) party? That's it? Anticlimactic :| . So why wasn't multithreading support considered in the first place? Lazy Rasmus Lerdorf?

Comment: PHP started as a specific-purpose personal project for Rasmus to track visits to his online resume: http://www.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php.  From there it grew into something "other".

Comment: @jnylen This seems to  be very bad answer. Multi-threading has been available in PHP since 2012. Check it out [**Pthreads**](http://pthreads.org). Also [**PHP App Server**](http://www.appserver.io) has been built with pthreads.

Comment: @jnylen I think you can improve your answer. Multithreading is available in PHP through [Pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) . Please check that.

Comment: I've learned a lot since 2012.  I would still never try to use multithreaded PHP.

Comment: "Uniquely among modern languages, PHP was born in a web server. Its strengths are tightly coupled to the context of request-oriented, server-side execution." -- https://slack.engineering/taking-php-seriously-cf7a60065329

Answer (score 10):

Read this URL i think it is help full to you.

PHP Multithreading – Faking It

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/20/php-multithreading-faking-it/

PHP doesn’t really support multi-threading per se but there are ways to do “fake” multithreading. Here’s one I saw in the PHPClasses.org newsletter –

[Multi-thread Simulation](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3953-PHP-Emulate-threads-using-separate-HTTP-requests.html).

Note that this class is intedend for use on a webserver, as opposed to running PHP scripts from a command line (or similar). Check the end of this post for some alternatives you can try if you’re using PHP as a stand-alone scripting language.